# Proof of Multinomial covariance matrix

Tags: binomial-distribution, covariance, multinomial-distribution

Let $X \sim Multinomial(n,p)$. The data takes the form $X=(X_1, \dots, X_k)$ where each $X_j$ is a count. Let $p=(p_1, \dots, p_k)$ where $p_j \geq 0$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{k}p_j =1$.

The variance-covariance matrix of $X$ is:
$$V(X) = \begin{pmatrix} np_1(1-p_1) & -np_1p_2 & \dots & -np_1 p_k \\
-np_1p_2 &  np_2(1-p_2) & \dots & -np_2p_k \\ 
\vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \vdots \\
-np_1p_k & -np_2p_k &\dots &np_k(1-p_k)
\end{pmatrix} $$

I understand the terms on the diagonal since $X_j \sim Binomial(n,p_j)$, but I'm stuck in proving the expressions of the terms outside the diagonal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favourite way to prove this is to use the equality
$$2\mathrm{cov}[A,B]=\mathrm{var}[A+B]-\mathrm{var}[A]-\mathrm{var}[B]$$

$X_i+X_j$ is Binomial$(n,p_1+p_2)$, so
$$2\mathrm{cov}[X_i,X_j]=n(p_1+p_2)(1-p_1-p_2)-np_1(1-p_1)-np_2(1-p_2)$$
and most of that just cancels to give the answer